# SQL / PHP How to pull data from a table and place it in variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Assuming I have a uniqid key in my table and that same key is sent to my site in a get method, how do I pull that specific key out and assign all the data from the table to variables. This is what I have so far but cant seem to figure it out.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * 
       FROM todo_item2 as ti INNER JOIN todo_category2 as tc ON ti.todo_id = tc.todo_id'
       WHERE todo_id = :todo_id";

$statement1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$statement1 -> execute(array(
    'todo_id' =>$id
));

while ($row = $statement1->fetch()) 
{
    $text = $row['todo'];
    $cat = $row['category'];
    $percent = $row['precent'];
    $date = $row['due_date'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Start the Load
$query1 = "SELECT * 
           FROM todo_item2 as ti INNER JOIN todo_category2 as tc ON ti.todo_id = tc.todo_id
           WHERE ti.todo_id = :todo_id";

$statement1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$statement1 -> execute(array(
    'todo_id' =>$id
));

// Make Sure the Data Exists
if( $statement1->rowCount() == 0 )
{
    die('Please Enter a Valid ID Tag - (id)');
}


while($row = $statement1->fetch())
{
    $text = $row['todo'];
    $cat = $row['category'];
    $percent = $row['percent'];
    $date = $row['due_date'];
}
```

Comment: Took some serious work but i eventually fooled with it enough to get it to work. Still not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You should ready about what `execute` actually does .. the parameters to `execute` (and I assume you're using PDO or something similar here) are the tokens of the query.  What you want is something like:

```
$query = " ... WHERE todo_id = ?"
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   //$row is now an associative array of row values.
}
```

Comment: Can i save a variable in the while loop like: $text = $row['todo'];? its not like that for some reason.

Comment: Im not getting my data out of the table its just showing an error.

Comment: Not showing an error its just <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: text in edit.php</b> on line <b>183</b><br /> This is what its showing for a the variable $row['text'];

Comment: Yes the Query is fine. It has to do with the fetch i think. while ($row = $statement1->fetch()) 
{
    $text = $row['todo'];
    $cat = $row['category'];
    $percent = $row['precent'];
    $date = $row['due_date'];
}